# Replacement for target platform

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, target-platform

Is it possible to replace target platform with some other method in eclipse plugin development. My case is that I want to enable customer to generate a plugin project with some configurations and script and then compile it into jar plugin. When we as developer company compile this plugin, we used our proprietary target platform hosted on internal servers but when customer would compile it he would not have this access. So what is the recommended solution. I wanted something which I customer can run on command line instead of inside eclipse.

Comment: maven + Eclipse tycho would be used to run from the command line, but this still uses a target platform. To build a plugin you have to provide the build with all the classes it references so I don't see an alternative to a target platform. Why do they need to build a new plugin? Can't you write a standard single plugin that reads its configuration when it starts?

Comment: I already saw tycho option but as far as I know it only supports target platform with software site. Btw Is it possible to compile my plugin with all plugins which come with target platform?

Comment: You can use good old [PDE Build](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/User_Guide#PDE_Build) instead of Tycho/Maven for that.

Comment: Don't know how to mark as answer but howlger solved my issue with PDE